# Recurring system.log process: "com.apple.dpd: Service exited with abnormal code: 75" - Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: catalina, bug, console

I've been trying to remove this weird recurring process that happens every second in my system.log:

```
Sep 27 23:45:12 User-iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.dpd[1749]): Service exited with abnormal code: 75
Sep 27 23:45:12 User-iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.dpd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.
```

It'll also randomly throw this SIGKILL message:

```
Sep 27 23:51:14 User-iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.05000000-0200-0000-0000-000000000000[2434]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[122]
```

I've tried a few things so far:

1. Disabled SIP in recovery mode, ran `sudo mount -uw /` in terminal after booting and removed the com.apple.dpd.plist file from System/Library/LaunchDaemons
2. Re-formatted my hard drive and did a fresh install of Catalina. Repeated the above step.

I've been Googling non-stop so has anyone experienced this or know how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I'm not sure if there will be unintended consequences to doing this but I removed the dpd daemon from /usr/libexec/, which is a hidden folder (literally dragged it into the trash and removed it). No more recurring messages!

[DPD in the Man Pages](https://www.manpagez.com/man/8/dpd/)